# Use part of string as variable?

Tags: sql, string, variables, teradata

There's something I'm trying to do, I don't think it's possible but maybe I'm wrong.

It is in teradata so I can't use variables.

I have a table that contains different messages as strings:

Ie, column MSG contains `'Hello, how are you today?'`

And a table that contains different users with user_id and user_name.

Then, separately, I am using:

```
SELECT
  MSG,
  USER_ID,
  USER_NAME
FROM MSG_TABLE
INNER JOIN PERSON_TABLE
  ON PERSON_ID.ID = MSG_TABLE.ID
```

Is there a way to modify the message in the message table, so that when I select the message, part of the string acts as if retrieving information from the person table?

So that the MSG in the table would be something like `'Hello @@@, how are you today?'` and when I run the query above I would get

```
 | 'Hello Peter, how are you today?' | 1765 | Peter.
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables in the question* would be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the value in the 'MSG' column as something like this:

> 'Hello {username}, how are you today?'

Then, you can just use the REPLACE function

```
SELECT
  OREPLACE(MSG, '{username}', USER_NAME) AS NEW_MSG,
  USER_ID,
  USER_NAME
FROM MSG_TABLE
INNER JOIN PERSON_TABLE
  ON PERSON_ID.ID = MSG_TABLE.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Terradata, but this should work :

```
SELECT
  OREPLACE(MSG, '@@@', USER_NAME),
  USER_ID,
  USER_NAME
FROM MSG_TABLE
INNER JOIN PERSON_TABLE
  ON PERSON_ID.ID = MSG_TABLE.ID
```

Given : [OREPLACE](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/4EDh6YkzUpaKM7mjAXO1PA)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your existing pattern:

```
select 
  strtok(MSG, ',', 1) || ' ' || USER_NAME || ', ' || strtok(MSG, ',', 2), USER_ID, USER_NAME
FROM MSG_TABLE
INNER JOIN PERSON_TABLE
  ON PERSON_ID.ID = MSG_TABLE.ID;
```